# Domain name not resolving

Tags: networking, centos

I have centos6 with physical firewall of Cisco ASDM6.1. When I am executing dig gmail.com or dig google.com, it gives me following error:

```
connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

To get the domain resolved, do I need to make any change in firewall?  If yes, then what change do I need to make in CISCO ASDM Firewall?  If not, then how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If DNS is working fine then check whether firewall is blocking DNS port. if so open the DNS port and see whether it works.

Comment: How can I check that firewall if blocking the DNS port? if so then how can I open?

Comment: Cisco has mostly provided guidance for it. search for it. dns port is udp/tcp 53. this is what i can tell